# Using Arduino BLE Nano to switch an electric circuit on and off

Tags: relay

I'd like to use an Arduino Nano BLE to activate or deactivate an electric circuit.

I intend to use a relay to do so, but activating a relay seems to require a current with more intensity than what we can get out of a digital output (about 20 mA).

Is there a way to get more intensity out of a BLE nano ?

Are there others components that could behave the same way as a relay but could react from a digital output ?

Comment: You can use an NPN transistor such as a 2n2222 with a 1K or so resistor on the base to actuate a small relay.  Put a diode backwards across the coil.  You will see this circuit published everywhere.  Or you can use the optoisolated version common on those cheap relay boards.  Make sure your relay is rated to handle your ultimate load.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the comment. This could be an answer isn't it ? May I ask you for a reference link about how to use an NPN transistor with an Arduino ?